# Replacing a sum by a contour integral

Tags: contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am studying a paper [1] that makes the change from a sum over $N$ terms
\begin{equation}
U_{X}(t)=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^{N} \prod_{k \neq j}\left(\frac{f(x_j,x_k);t )}{x_{j}-x_{k}}\right)
\end{equation}
To a contour integral:
\begin{equation}
U_{X}(t)=\frac{1}{N} \oint  \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2\pi \mathrm{i}}\prod_{k = 1}\left(\frac{f(u,x_k;t )}{u-x_{k}}\right)
\end{equation}
**Under what conditions are we allowed to make this change?** Is this a simple property that I am missing/ am supposed to know? I am sorry if this question is basic, I do not understand what happened there. There is no particular condition of the size of $N$ (i.e finite or not)

The actual equations are:
\begin{equation}
U_{A}(t)=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{\alpha=1}^{N} \prod_{\gamma \neq \alpha}\left(\frac{a_{\alpha}-a_{\gamma}-(i t / N)}{a_{\alpha}-a_{\gamma}}\right) e^{-\left(t^{2} / 2 N\right)-i t a_{\alpha}}
\end{equation}
To
\begin{equation}
U_{A}(t)=-\frac{1}{i t} \oint \frac{d u}{2 \pi i} \prod_{\gamma=1}^{N}\left(\frac{u-a_{\gamma}-(i t / N)}{u-a_{\gamma}}\right) e^{-i t u-\left(t^{2} / 2 N\right)}
\end{equation}
[1]: Brézin, E., & Hikami, S. (1997). Spectral form factor in a random matrix theory. Physical Review E, 55(4), 4067. link: https://journals.aps.org/pre/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevE.55.4067

Comment: You can try to apply catchy theorem and find the poles. I guess the contour has to contain all the a

Comment: Here the contour integral would simplify to the sum of residues, but wouldn't the residues be without the denominator?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, I tried to simplify the problem by trying to keep a general setting. If my notation brought inconsistencies, please look only at the actual equations for $U_A(t)$. I will edit my question later.

Comment: see my answer below for the coefficients. Only a part of the denominator goes away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_i(z),i=1...N$ be complex analytic functions and $z_i$ be complex numbers. Than we have the identity:

$$\sum_i \left(f_i(z_i)\prod_{j\ne i}\frac{f_j(z_i)}{z_i-z_j}\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma} dz \prod_i\frac{f_i(z)}{z-z_i} [1]$$

for every contour $\gamma$ enclosing all the $z_i$.

You can derive [1] starting from right member and applying Cauchy theorem.
Note that the poles are at $z_1,..,z_N$  and evaluate the residues in the standard way as a limit.

[1] than is enough to derive the "actual equations" with the proper choice of functions $f_i(z)$:

$f_i(z)=\left(z-a_{i}-(i t / N)\right) e^{-i t z -t^2/2N}$